# Android setOnTouchListener not working in fragment

Tags: android, fragment, ontouchlistener

I am trying to control the OnTouchListener(up and down) in a fragment. I implemented the  `setOnTouchListener` method but it is not working.

I would simply like to show an "Up" Toast when an up touch occurs, or a "Down" Toast when a down touch occurs.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.strada_chefs_1, container,
            false);

    rootView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event)) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: did you add some Log.d inside onTouch?

Comment: is onCreateView returning `rootView` ?

Comment: what is your exception post log cat

Comment: i only can Down message always

Comment: Is your layout clickable or focusable? If it is not, touch events will not be caught.

Answer (score 1):

Try returning **true** in `onTouch` call-back.  If you return **false** it means that the event should be processed by someone else.  OnTouch event consists on down - move - up, and if **false** is returned by `OnTouchListener` at any point, the rest of the event is processed elsewhere and not by your `OnTouchListener`.  Your code receives `ACTION_DOWN`, but since it returns **false**, the rest of the event is handeled elsewhere.